# If I send a hotfix to a user, will they continue to get updates from the Play Store?

Tags: android, google-play, apk, updates

Say I have an application that users have installed from the Play Store, if one of my users reports a bug and I want to send them a patched version of the app to test, they can install it to their phone just fine. But if I then update the app on the Play Store, will the user get the update? My testing seems to indicate this is the case, but is there any gotchas?

The way my build process works is that each time I build, it gets a higher version code, so the patched version will have a higher version code that the one currently in the Play Store and then the version I upload to the Play Store *after* sending my user the patch will have a higher version code again.

Comment: Why not just push the fix to the playstore directly? If its a problem in the app, shouldn't you fix it for everyone?

Comment: If both Apps are signed with the same key it is no problem.

Comment: @RaghavSood that's true, but if it's only affecting a particular device (which I personally don't have access to), I want to test it before I send it out to everyone. I will *eventually* send it out to everyone, though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm taking a decently wild guess here, but it *should* work, provided the following are met:

1. The version code of the apk on Google Play is higher than that of the hotfix
2. The user originally installed the app from Google Play to begin with, and only updated it via side loading.
3. The hotfix and the Google Play update are both signed with the same key.

I'm decently sure this will work, as I recall a long discussion about this on one of the android google groups that ended with success. I unfortunately cannot find it right now.

If you do try it out, please post back with the results.

Comment: 2 doesn't sound like a necessary precondition. as long as they're both signed from the same key, does it matter if its installed from the play store?

Comment: @DhruvGairola If the app wasn't originally installed from Google play, then Google doesn't know that you've installed it, and won't push updates for you.

Comment: i can verify that that is not true circa 2012. i have tested this myself. if you install an app directly from the apk, the play store will still push updates as long as conditions 1 and 3 are true.

Comment: Thanks, I'll test it out and give you the tick if it works :) @DhruvGairola in my particular case it doesn't matter, since it was installed from the Play Store originally anyway, but that's an interesting observation!

Comment: @DhruvGairola Did you install the app from google play at any time at all? Also, do you use titanium backup? It has the ability to link sideloaded apps to google play

Comment: nope. i installed the app directly from the apk (download the apk, open in device, install). updates were still pushed from the store. im fairly certain of this (as of mid-2012).

Comment: So I can confirm that if you side-install an APK that's signed with the same certificate as the Play Store version, you'll continue to get updates from the Play Store (as long as the version code increases as well). Thanks!

Comment: @DeanHarding Thank you for posting back with the results!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any issue with this workflow. As long as you increment the version number at each build.